# How to checked checkbox so that data will be send to next page

Tags: php, html

Refer to above title, i've a favor that i would like to ask all of you senpais.

This is my coding regarding this matters;

```
<?php

require ("config.php");
$link = mysqli_connect($h,$u,$p,$db)
   OR die(mysqli_error());

   $query = "select  BIL, HOTEL, TOTAL, address from HOTELS"
   OR DIE(mysql_error());
   $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

   echo "<table border=2>";
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))   { 

       //echo "<tr><td>".$row["BIL"]."</td>";
       echo "<tr><td>$row[HOTEL]</td>";
       //echo "<td>$row[TOTAL]</td>";
       echo "<td>$row[address]</td>";
       echo "<td><a href='edit.html?edit=$row[BIL]'>Edit</a></td>";
       echo "<td><a href='delete.php?del=$row[BIL] '>Delete</a></td>";
       echo "<td><input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' value='{$row['HOTEL'] }'></td></tr>" ;
   }
?>
</body>
</html>
<form action="hotel.html" method="get">
<input name="" type="submit" value="Add hotel" />
</form>
<form action="pilihan.php" method="get">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit    '])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['checkbox'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $selected) {
            echo $selected."</br>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

[image]
Whenever i tried to tick multiple box and hit submit, next page didnt produce any data. Any tips?

Comment: did you have put those check boxes inside the form tag ?

Comment: Your table in which you have multiple checkboxes are not in `form` tag and even you form is outside of `HTML` tag

Comment: oh its ok, i got it. Thanks!